# Entity Manager returning null for joined columns

Tags: java, jpa, entitymanager

I have three tables , a main table MAIN_TB with foreign keys to table TCHARS and TSTATUSES, when i persist MAIN_TB, re-query and display the saved record, the joined columns(tchars from TCHARS and t_status from TSTATUSES) are null but data is saved. what could i be missing?

Table MAIN_TB

```
@JoinColumn(name = "T_STATUS", referencedColumnName = "T_STATUS")
@ManyToOne
private Tstatuses tStatus;

@JoinColumn(name = "T_CHAR", referencedColumnName = "T_CHAR")
@ManyToOne
private Tchars tChar;
```

Table TCHARS

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "tChar")
private Collection<MainTb> mainTbCollection;
```

Table TSTATUSES

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "tStatus")
private Collection<MainTb> mainTbCollection;
```

Code

```
 public void saveMainTb(){
     MainTb mainTb = new MainTb();
     Tchars tchars = new Tchars();
     Tstatuses tstatuses = new Tstatuses();

     tchars.setTChar(new Short("1"));
     mainTb.setTChar(tchars);

     tstatuses.setTStatus(new Short("1"));
     mainTb.setTStatus(tstatuses);

     mainTb.setTName("test");
     em.persist(mainTb);

 }
```

Result

```
 ![Result][1]
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Share the query, you've used to re-query your persisted Object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since there is no cascading specified on either owning side or inverse side. I reckon you can try the following code to manually save all entity instances:

```
em.persist(tchars);
em.persist(tstatuses);
mainTb.setTChar(tchars);
mainTb.setTStatus(tstatuses);
em.persist(mainTb);
```

Comment: changed but no luck, `em.merge(tchars);
         em.merge(tstatuses);
         mainTb.setTChar(tchars);
         mainTb.setTStatus(tstatuses);
         em.merge(mainTb);` any other clue

Comment: I have just noticed that if the **MAIN_TB** table has data when deploying the Application, the fields display , but if the table is empty from the db, the fields don't display , here is a [link](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ykejk8cjk3i1px3/nLf1vGD5Hd)  to the testApp. Done on Netbeans and Oracle XE database.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the below code to your **tStatus** and **tChar**.

```
fetch=FetchType.EAGER
```

This will hit the performance, if you don't need to fetch the 2 above objects, always.

Instead, you can add the `fetch` clause in your query, to fetch the two child objects(**tStatus** and **tChar**), along with your `mainTb` object. This will save you the trouble and fetch all the child objects, you've specified in your `fetch` clause. Performance optimizer.

Comment: Changed my code to                                  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "tStatus",fetch= FetchType.EAGER)
    private Collection<MainTb> mainTbCollection;    and   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "tChar",fetch= FetchType.EAGER)
    private Collection<MainTb> mainTbCollection;   still no luck.

Comment: My re-query code is the findAll NamedQuery i.e '@NamedQuery(name = "Tchars.findAll", query = "SELECT t FROM Tchars t")',   then i call it in my boundary class(EJB stateless) ..  `public List<MainTb> populateMyList(){
         List<MainTb> mlist = em.createNamedQuery("MainTb.findAll").getResultList();
         return mlist;
     }` then inject the boundary class to my managed bean(Session Scoped).

Comment: I have just noticed that if the **MAIN_TB** table has data when deploying the Application, the fields display , but if the table is empty from the db, the fields don't display , here is a [link](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ykejk8cjk3i1px3/nLf1vGD5Hd)  to the testApp. Done on Netbeans and Oracle XE database.